# KairosDB-Kafka plugin is not receiving messages

Tags: apache-kafka, kairosdb

I am using [kafka-kairosdb](https://github.com/kairosdb/kairos-kafka) plugin for directly streaming kafka messages into kairosDB.

I built and successfully added plugin in `/lib` folder and from logs I see that plugin is running and is connected into my kafka topic. After sending message into this topic it is not proceed by plugin and it seems that it is stay on `for (MessageAndMetadata<byte[], byte[]> messageAndMetadata : m_stream)`.

I didn't change anything in configuration, except topic name for default stringparser to match my topic in kafka.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with incompatibility between plugin kafka version and my instance version. After changing it, it works well.